# Integral of xy function over a non centered ellipse

Tags: calculus, conic-sections, multiple-integral, change-of-variable

I am trying to understand a problem of integration - which does not look so complicated but I really struggle with a variable change. Here it is:
$$ D=\{(x,y)\in R^2:4(x-1)^2+9(y-1)^2<36,y>1,x-y>0\}$$
calculate $$\iint_D xydxdy $$.

The domain $D$ is an ellipse centred in $(1,1)$ which can be parametrized as:
$$x=1+3r\cos\theta,y=1+2r\sin\theta$$
which is the change of variable to be done. The jacobian for this change of variable is $6r$ and the domain can be described as:
$$D=\{(1+3r\cos\theta,1+2r\sin\theta):0<r<1,0<\theta<\arctan\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\}$$
hence the integral becomes:
$$6\int_0^{\arctan(3/2)}\int_0^1r+3r^2\cos\theta+2r^2\sin\theta+3r^3\sin(2\theta)drd\theta $$

My question is this: I really don't understand the upper limit in $\theta=\arctan(3/4)$ : why is it not $\pi/4$ ? Seems to me that this should be the good angle as the "left/up" side part of the domain is limited by the line $x=y$ which has a $\theta=\pi/4$ angle with horizontal lines... I am clearly missing something basic here but cannot figure out what... Any help would be very much appreciated !

Marc

EDIT: just to clarify, I do understand that 3/2 comes from writing that $x=y$ on the ellipse boundary which, under the change of variables, means $1+3r\cos\theta=1+2r\sin\theta\Rightarrow\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}=\tan\theta=\frac{3}{2}$, but the point is that with my eyes I see $\pi/4$... so there clearly is a property of change of variables I don't understand...

Comment: The parameter $\theta$ in the equation of the ellipse is not the same as the polar angle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Standard_parametric_representation

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Thank you so very much for your answer !! This looks a lot like the critical point : I was conflating the two angles. However, then, when using the substitution above, it seems to me to be a lot like a polar substitution, however with factors multiplying  the sine and cosine functions: are they responsible for the difference between this $\theta$ and the "real" polar angle ? In addition to a change of origin, if I am not mistaken... ?

Comment: No change of origin, just look at [this figure](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/75/Elliko-sk.svg/808px-Elliko-sk.svg.png): $t$ is the parameter corresponding to point $P$ on the ellipse.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Then, when one does the above change of variable, this means that we set a frame of reference with its origin at the center of the ellipse and that the $\theta$ parameter must be understood following the La Hire interpretation described in the Wikipedia page you pointed to ? Thanks again a lot : I am beginning to understand things a bit :-)

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Thanks once again for your answer (I had not seen before posting my second reply, sorry !!). However, in the change of variable $x=1+3r\cos\theta,y=1+2r\sin\theta$, there is a shift of the origin from (0,0) to (1,1), isn't there ? Or am I missing something ? Sorry, my questions might seem simple minded but I really have a difficulty in this process of change of variables... or should I just see it as a parametrization of the ellipse ?

Comment: Yes, the center of the ellipse is at $(1,1)$. Hence the translation.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca additionnally, would you consider posting your comment as answer so that I may accept it ?

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Thank you so very much for your kind and efficient help !!